# is llvm/clang internal thread-safe?

Tags: multithreading, clang, llvm

I'd like to parse source files (*.cpp*) using llvm/clang c api: `clang_parseTranslationUnit`, then  `clang_indexTranslationUnit` , `clang_getDiagnosticSetFromTU`, `clang_tokenize` as fast is i can. So i'd like to parse first and then do other routines concurrently. Is it safe to do some translation unit operations concurrently? Are there any methods to switch on/off thread-safety?

**UPDATE**: i've tried to tokenize and index concurrently and i'm getting an error:

> Assertion failed: (acquired && "Concurrent access to ASTUnit!"),
>   function start, file
>   /Users/user/Documents/dev/src/llvm_34/tools/clang/lib/Frontend/ASTUnit.cpp,
>   line 2947. libclang: crash detected during indexing TU

How to enable thread safety?

Comment: What did you do to implement the concurrency?

Comment: used GCD queues. parse is done in the first block and then tokenize, index and getting diagnostics are done in one GCD queue group concurrectly

Comment: What makes you think that dynamic allocation is threadsafe?

Comment: Why not? I'm not sure about clang internals but it seems possible to perform that operations concurrently since they use read-only access for AST (which is created during parsing) most likely. Anyway i'm just asking for the people who know for sure so feel free to answer my question

Comment: Don't know much about Clang and parallelism.  Am very interested in program analysis and parallelism; have been building such tools (not Clang-based) for awhile. They are pretty hard to get right; data races are hell, you just don't want to ever have them.

Comment: i was able to make it working (clang routines) if using serial queue, but it takes 3x times more comparably to concurrent execution. so i'm still looking for the way to do it concurrent